# Cyberlink PowerDirector 9 - Importing mov files in the timeline removes audio?

Tags: video, quicktime, video-editing

I'm trying to trim a few mov files using PowerDirector. When I drag them into the timeline, no audio track shows; when I click play no sound is heard. However the files do have sound, it gets removed only when added to the timeline for editing.

I need these files trimmed and then transformed into .flv

Why do you think this happens? Or, can you recommend me another piece of software?

Thank you,
Cris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerDirector probably lacks the correct audio codec used for the audio inside the MOV file (obviously check you are running the latest version first).

You could play the file back in VLC and check the codec information (under Tools->Codec Information I think). Quicktime probably has a similar screen for showing codec information.

Once you have determined the codec, you basically have two options:

1. Find another movie maker type
   program that supports MOV files, the
   audio codec, and the video codec,
   and also has other features you need
   (eg outputs FLV).
2. Extract the audio track from the MOV
   file and reencode it to mp3 or
   another audio format PowerDirector
   can import. There are several tools
   that can probably do this (depending on the codec), but
   FFmpeg is probably the most likely
   to work.

The second option is probably the easiest, there is documentation and examples on FFmpeg use all over the net, for extracting audio (it can also convert it in the same step).

Comment: I've trimmed the videos with Quicktime Pro and transformed them into FLVs with another software. Thank you for the advice, I will definitely use it for other videos!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Jus try unlinking the video so that video and audio are separate. Delete the corresponding audio of your video. Insert the desired audio track to your video and it must work